# store permanently properties in mailitem and related .msg file

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office

I need to save permanently some custom information inside an Outlook Mailitem and retrieve them back.
My case scenario is the following: I select an email in Outlook 2013 explorer, write inside that email some information, save it on my disk as .msg file, delete the email from the Inbox Outlook folder, open the .msg file as Outlook.MailItem and read that information in order to keep them or change them.

I'm using the Outlook.ItemProperties.Add() method to add a custom ItemProperty inside the selected MailItem.

When I get a MailItem from the .msg I'm not able to find that properties.

I've used [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm)->Miscellaneous->OpenIMsgOnIstg function to check the .msg and I've noted that all properties are in the GetProps tab.

My question is: How can I read the properties?

Here is the code to write the properties and save the mail as .msg:

```
Outlook.Application outApp= new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem mail= null;
try { mail = (Outlook.MailItem)outApp.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem; }
catch {
   if (outApp.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
      mail = (Outlook.MailItem)outApp .ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
   else { // ERROR  }
}
Outlook.ItemProperty prop01 = mail.ItemProperties.Add("MyProperty01", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olText);
prop01.Value = "hola";
Outlook.ItemProperty prop02 = mail.ItemProperties.Add("MyProperty02", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olNumber);
prop02.Value = 23;
mail.Save();
mail.SaveAs(@"C:\WorkSpace\mail.msg", Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
if (mail != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mail);
if (outlookObj != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outApp );
```

Here is my code to read the properties from the .msg after I've deleted the email in Outlook:

```
Outlook.Application outApp= new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem msgMail=(Outlook.MailItem)outApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
msgMail = (Outlook.MailItem)outApp.Session.OpenSharedItem(@"C:\WorkSpace\mail.msg");
Outlook.ItemProperties mailProps = msgMail.ItemProperties;
Outlook.ItemProperty pr = mailProps["MyProperty01"]; // pr IS NULL
```

But OutlookSpy [shows](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gm6e6k39u4q5g5m/MSGProperties.jpg?dl=0) the properties are in the .msg file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem following [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/85f92d4c-282f-46d6-a698-daeb5714b8f0/propertyaccessorgetproperty-always-returns-exception?forum=outlookdev#e28798fa-2406-4248-8512-186cab6076e9) bypassing solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mailitem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` and pass the DASL property name shown by OutlookSpy (I am its author).

Comment: Your solution very often produce a 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException <0x8004010F>: Property ... unknown or not found'. If I write a string property called 'Prop01' is it ok if I use in the GetProperty method the string 'http ://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Prop01/0x0000001E' ???

Comment: Try to remove the /0x0000001E part - Outlook does not like the property type specified for the properties in the "string" namespace.

Comment: Unfortunately by using the 'http ://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Prop‌​‌​01' string it produces the same Exception above. Any other hint?

Comment: Keep in mind that OpenSharedItem creates a temporary message, and some properties might not copied there. If you create a new MSG file using msgMail.SaveAs(..., olMsg), do you see your custom properties preserved?

Comment: No, I don't. What drives me crazy is that in some cases your first idea works fine... but not always. Anyway a possible solution is [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/85f92d4c-282f-46d6-a698-daeb5714b8f0/propertyaccessorgetproperty-always-returns-exception?forum=outlookdev#e28798fa-2406-4248-8512-186cab6076e9). Thank you Dmitry.

Comment: Using Redemption (I am its author) is an option, RDOSession.GetMessageFromMsgFile (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) will not try to be smart and create a temporary copy.